# Определение слову "шутка" в понимании психолингвистики

Tags: психолингвистика

Здравствуйте!
Помогите, пожалуйста, дать определение слову "шутка" в понимании социолингвистики и/или психолингвистики.
Делаю курсовую, преподаватель не принимает определения из словаря Даля, Ушакова, Ожегова и т.п.
Буду очень благодарна ответившему!

С уважением,
Е. Серая

Answer (score 3, accepted):

КОгда мы учились, таких дисциплин у нас не было. Их названия звучали только где-то в обзоре. Вы курсовую пишете по социолингвистике? Тогда одного определения будет мало... Но, может, вот такое Вас к чему-нибудь подтолкнет?
*Шутка – это  такой  вид текста, в котором находит свое отражение национальная психология со всеми образующими ее чувствами, обычаями, вкусами и установками, со всеми особенностями национального бытия, национальной истории, а также проявляются интернациональные связи и взаимодействия.*

Comment: Спасибо огромное! (курсовая по психолингвистике, тема "Языковые и энциклопедические знания как база для понимания шутки") То, что Вы написали, идеально подходит.Ссылку на источник не укажете? 
Ещё раз спасибо!
С уважением,
Серая Е.

Comment: http://www.lib.ua-ru.net/diss/cont/204198.html

Comment: Спасибо! Всё получилось!

Comment: Мне было интересно читать материал по теме, спасибо и Вам за вопрос.